# Output a for loop into a array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, unix

I need the below 4th row idle outputs to be put into a array and then take a average out of the same . below is lparstat output of an aix system.

```sh
$ lparstat 2 10

System configuration: type=Shared mode=Uncapped smt=4 lcpu=16 mem=8192MB psize=16 ent=0.20

%user  %sys  %wait  %idle physc %entc  lbusy   app  vcsw phint  %nsp  %utcyc
----- ----- ------ ------ ----- ----- ------   --- ----- ----- -----  ------
  2.6   1.8    0.0   95.5  0.02   9.5    0.0  5.05   270     0   101   1.42
  2.8   1.6    0.0   95.6  0.02   9.9    1.9  5.38   258     0   101   1.42
  0.5   1.4    0.0   98.1  0.01   5.5    2.9  5.17   265     0   101   1.40
  2.8   1.3    0.0   95.8  0.02   8.9    0.0  5.37   255     0   101   1.42
  2.8   2.0    0.0   95.2  0.02  10.8    1.9  4.49   264     0   101   1.42
  4.2   1.7    0.0   94.1  0.02  12.2    0.0  3.66   257     0   101   1.42
  0.5   1.5    0.0   98.0  0.01   6.3    1.9  3.35   267     0   101   1.38
  3.1   2.0    0.0   94.9  0.02  12.1    2.9  3.07   367     0   101   1.41
  2.3   2.2    0.0   95.5  0.02   9.8    0.0  3.40   259     0   101   1.42
 25.1  25.5    0.0   49.4  0.18  89.6    2.6  2.12   395     0   101   1.44
```

I have made a script like this but need to press enter to get the output .

```sh
$ for i in ` lparstat 2 10 | tail -10 | awk '{print $4}'`
> do
> read arr[$i]
> echo arr[$i]
> done
arr[94.0]
arr[97.7]
arr[94.9]
arr[91.0]
arr[98.1]
arr[97.7]
arr[93.0]
arr[94.8]
arr[97.9]
arr[89.2]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried this but need to press enter everytime .

Comment: Welcome to SO, apart from what oguz ismail sir mentioned, kindly do add expected output too in your question itself with CODE TAGS.

Comment: That looks like a good script! Plese edit your question and post it inside your question. Now it may be just easier to calculate the avarage inside awk: `awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum/NR }`

Comment: Please take care to not revert useful edits by others when you update your question.

Comment: If you genuinely want the values in an array, Bash supports `read -a arr <<<$(lparstat 2 10 | tail -n 10 | awk '{print $4}')`

Comment: @Biswajit, Could you please check my solution once and let know if that helped you?

Answer (score 2):

Your script only needs a small improvement to calculate the average. You can do that inside `awk` right away:

```
lparstat 2 10 | tail -n 10 | awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum / NR }'
```

The `tail -n 10` takes 10 last lines.

`{ sum += $4 }` is calculated for each line - it sums the values at 4th column.

Then `END` block executes after the whole file is read. The `{ print sum / NR }` prints the average. `NR` is "Number of Records", where one record is one line, so it's number of lines.

Notes:

- backticks ` are discouraged. The modern `$( ... )` syntax is much preferred.
- The "for i in `cmd`" or more commonly `for i in $(...)` is a common antipattern in bash. Use `while read -r line` when reading lines from a command, like `cmd | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done` or in bash `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(cmd)`

Comment: Thanks .. i was able to create a script for cpu performance ..

Comment: cat cpu-idle.sh
IDLE=$(lparstat 2 10 | tail -n 10 | awk '{ sum += $4 } END { print sum / NR }')
NUM=100
USED=$(echo "$NUM - $IDLE"|bc)
echo "CPU inuse $USED"%""